# Execute htmlunit code from PHP

Tags: java, php, htmlunit

I have developed an `htmlunit` code,which is a `java` code, to scrap a website.

Can anyone suggest me how can I can call my `htmlunit` code in`PHP`script?

Answer (score 0):

You can use PHP's shell_exec()

[PHP's shell_exec()](http://www.php.net/manual/de/function.shell-exec.php)